# select like em mais de 3 milhões de linhas

Tags: mysql, autocompletar, operador-like

Tenho uma tabela do Maxmind, com mais de 3 milhões de cidades. Criei os *índices* para um select simples e está com desempenho satisfatório.

O problema é que estou usando um autocomplete e para isso meu select usa `like`, mas sempre retorna *timeout* (Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded).

Optei por usar `MyISAM` por ser uma tabela com baixa ou nenhuma alteração.

Pelo que andei lendo, 3 milhões não é uma quantidade excessiva, mas não sei como devo proceder para otimizar essa busca.

---

```
CREATE TABLE `cidades` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pais` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `regiao` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cidade` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titulo` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lon` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ID` (`id`),
  KEY `CITY` (`cidade`),
  KEY `ID_2` (`id`,`cidade`,`titulo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3166036 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
select cidade.titulo
from city
where cidade.titulo like '%Rio de Janeiro%'
```

Comment: De fato, havia testado com `like 'Rio de Janeiro%'` e o tempo de resposta foi praticamente idêntico ao select. Então o problema seria o **%** no inicio? Dessa forma ele faz uso dos índices?

Answer (score 5):

## Causa do desempenho ruim

Usar `%` no início do parâmetro do `like` causa um *full table scan*. Ele impede que o SGBDR utilize o índice da tabela, necessitando ler o campo por completo sempre. Esta então se torna efetivamente uma operação excessiva para 3 milhões de linha.

## Solução limitada

Removendo o `%` do início, o SGBDR será então capaz de pegar os primeiros caracteres antes do `%` é analisar diretamente o índice para fazer um filtro inicial dos resultados. Só então ele vai testar o `like` contra o valor completo das poucas linhas selecionadas.

O MySQL tem inclusive uma opção para definir quantos caracteres devem ser incluídos no índice de campos de texto.

Retirar o `%` do início resolve o problema de desempenho, só que pode não atender o requisito se o auto-completar for do tipo que busca parcialmente em todo o texto. Nesse caso seria melhor mudar a abordagem, isto é, não usar `like`.

## Solução completa

Uma alternativa seria [Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) provida pelo MySQL. Não tenho dados sobre o desempenho, pois não usei esta funcionalidade no MySQL ainda.

Outra alternativa mais avançado seria usar uma ferramenta como o [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/), um motor de busca desenvolvido em Java usado por muitos sites e projetos e que pode ser integrado no seu *back end* com PHP.

Comment: São 2 opções que não conhecia. Vou dar uma lida agora. TKS.

Comment: Vale citar engines próprias de indexação mais populares como o ElasticSearch.